# NFC tags read/write operations

Tags: smartcard, nfc, rfid, apdu

1. I would like to know which protocol is used for the read/write operations to the NFC tags are used. According to my understanding after the tag is placed on the NFC reader, it is powered and set to the ready state. Then the ‘application’ protocol for read/write operation is used. The exact format and the content of commands used for read/write is not specified in ISO 14443 and it is dependent on a tag hardware/manufacturer and will be different for

   - FeliCa
   - Mifare
   - Innovision
   - etc tags

so there is no way how to handle NFC tags read/write operations with the single implementation.

2. Are there any tags, which supports the APDU 7816-4 commands for read/write operations?

BR
STeN

Comment: Though interesting, this is really not a programming question - it's far more about the hardware

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment - this is related!! I am expecting to be asked to program the simple program for writing on NFC tags and I need to know how/what should be done in order do discuss it with the customer and later program of course:))

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're only working with NDEF then Android provides a single application-layer implementation that should work with all four standard NFC formats. Otherwise, you'll either have to bring your own or use Android's built-in support for Mifare Classic and Ultralight, in which case you obviously won't have a single universal implementation.
2. I think DESfire does, but I'm not completely sure. I'm not sure why you're asking – if you want to be able to use a single universal implementation with minimal effort then it's better to use NDEF since the support is built-in.